# Prevent input type from XSS attacks

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, xss

I get the value from input type like this:

```
var num        = $(document).find('#num').val();
```

I've tried to avoid the input type from XSS attacks with the following code:

```
num = jQuery(num).text().replace( 'script', '' ) ;
```

but it's not working.Any other ideas ?

Comment: If the user is supposed to type some HTML in the `'#num'` control you'll probably need a full-fledged HTML sanitisation library. It the user input is not supposed to be HTML, just don't try to execute it as such.

Comment: An example: typing `rm -rf /*` in a textarea doesn't imply any danger. However, if you execute the raw textarea input in your shell it can do harm.

Answer (score 1):

Even if this code works, you cant prevent xss attacks with javascript. if you want to do it with this:    `$(document).find('#num').val($(document).find('#num').val().replace('script',''));`

Now you have value in you input which script strings deleted but what if someone write `<scscriptript>` in in your input? after script string deleted in middle, there will be another script tag. You have to check your inputs in server side.